# Problem in downloading the file using sharepoint copy.asmx

Tags: python, web-services, sharepoint, download

I am trying to download the file from the document using sharepoint webservices called copy.asmx. its onlt 100 kb file size.

But its not downloading the file.

The web services iteself return empty stream (out byte[] Stream) in the web service response. is that any memory issue.

Also it returning like "download_document()out of memory"

Note: I am using the MFP printer to view this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below function. you need to pass FileURL(Full web url for document), Title(Pass name you want to give for downloaded file.)

```
public string DownLoadfiletolocal(string FileURL, string Title)
{

//Copy.Copy is a webservice object that I consumed.

Copy.Copy CopyObj = new Copy.Copy();
CopyObj.Url = SiteURL + "/_vti_bin/copy.asmx"; // Dynamically passing SiteURL
NetworkCredential nc2 = new NetworkCredential();
nc2.Domain = string.Empty;
nc2.UserName = _UserName;
nc2.Password = _Password;


string copySource = FileURL; //Pass full url for document.

Copy.FieldInformation myFieldInfo = new Copy.FieldInformation();
Copy.FieldInformation[] myFieldInfoArray = { myFieldInfo };
byte[] myByteArray;

// Call the web service
uint myGetUint = CopyObj.GetItem(copySource, out myFieldInfoArray, out myByteArray);

// Convert into Base64 String
string base64String;
base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);

// Convert to binary array
byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

// Create a temporary file to write the text of the form to
string tempFileName = Path.GetTempPath() + "\\" + Title;

// Write the file to temp folder
FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
fs.Write(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
fs.Close();

return tempFileName;

}
```

Comment: this function need to pass credentials along with full url for the document you want to download. I think that would be enough for you